# How to modify the coordinates of a shapefile geometry using GeoTools?

Tags: shapefile, geometry, java, geotools

I have a shapefile with some polygons. I would like to change the height for this elements using Java. The rest of the attributes should be the same. I've thought using GeoTools but I haven't found how to implement this.

Any help?

Answer (score 3):

The following is assuming that you know how to read and write a FeatureCollection in geotools.

```
SimpleFeatureCollection inVector = "read it"
SimpleFeatureCollection outVector = FeatureCollections.newCollection();
String elevationFieldName = "elev";

int size = inVector.size();
FeatureIterator<SimpleFeature> inFeatureIterator = inVector.features();
while( inFeatureIterator.hasNext() ) {
    SimpleFeature feature = inFeatureIterator.next();
    feature.setAttribute(elevationFieldName, yourNewElevation);
    outVector.add(feature);
}
inFeatureIterator.close();
```

Then just write outVector to a new shapefile.

Reading and writing is covered in the tutorials: http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/tutorial/